# Connect to Amazon S3 from hosting

Tags: amazon-s3, video-streaming, server-to-server

Ok I been Googling for a while now, and i can't seem to find a good tutorial on how to connect to an Amazon S3 account from my hosting server. If anyones knows of a good step by step tutorial please post url.

Here's a little bit more info on what im trying to accomplish. im using Vidiscript which is a YouTube clone I want to save on disk space and bandwidth by uploading all videos to an amazon S3 account and i also needed away to mass upload since vidiscript doesn't offer a free way to upload more that one video at a time. I wanted to create a cron job that checks for newly upload videos and adds info to database. but I still have to come up with a way to create a preview thumbnail for videos so I might have to upload to hosting then create thumbnails then upload to amazon S3 account then delete files from hosting.

But either way I need to connect to my amazon S3 account from hosting server.

I will be streaming all videos using flowplayer's pseudostreaming plugin.

any alternative solutions to save on bandwidth and mass upload would also be appreciated.

Comment: Depends on your language and platform.  For instance, with Ruby - you can use the aws-s3 plugin at http://amazon.rubyforge.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map AWS S3 directory to your local using [FUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace). There are several projects to achieve that.

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/s3fuse/
- http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Vidiscript is based on PHP so I'd go with [php-aws](http://github.com/tylerhall/php-aws/)

Answer (score 0):

This is in response to the part of the problem

"I also needed away to mass upload since vidiscript doesn't offer a free way to upload more that one video at a time. I wanted to create a cron job that checks for newly upload videos and adds info to database"

Here's a beta of free bulk upload.

http://dev.vidiscript.co.uk/VidiScriptOriginalNew/

username:admin password:admin

click on upload ,note that upload form is in 2 parts.

you can setup a cron job for this file `http://youServer/VidiscriptFolder/process.php`

you can download the updated version of vidiscript from [vidiscript.co.uk](http://vidiscript.co.uk)